# can't display multiple routes on map android

Tags: android, maps

I am using google map to show show routes between source and destination. I am not able to show multiple routes between them. only one route is displaying. Please help to show multiple routes

My code is as below:

1) route parser

```
  /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes;
        JSONArray jLegs;
        JSONArray jSteps;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing  l routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);


                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString((list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString((list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }


        return routes;
    }


    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
    private List<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));

            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
```

2) Path creating code

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            String distance = "";
            String duration = "";


            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                    List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    if(j==0){   // Get distance from the list
                        distance = (String)point.get("distance");
                        continue;
                    }else if(j==1){ // Get duration from the list
                        duration = (String)point.get("duration");
                        continue;
                    }

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions

                lineOptions.clickable(true);
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(6);
                lineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);

                Log.d("onPostExecute","onPostExecute lineoptions decoded");

            }

            distanceR.setText(" ("+distance+")");
            timeRequired.setText(duration);
            // String s="Distance:"+distance + ", Duration:"+duration;
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route

                mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);

        }
    }
```

Note : if i give value of i in traversing route, it shows another one but still show only one route at one time. I need to show all possible routes together with different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks if anybody looked into it..

The mistake was , i just needed to include mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions); inside loop

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making points and lineOptions global make them local to your method

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
    Points points = new ArrayList<>();
    PolylineOptions lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
     ..............

}
```

When you make them global and each time create a new instance it override the previous one.

Comment: Hi kunu,
Thanks for replying.. But i just solved it by including mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions); inside loop... can you please tell me how to highlight selected route?